# Getting an error using grunt serve?

Tags: sass, jekyll, bourbon

I am using [Generator-jekyllrb](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) and it has a grunt task which can't seem to process some scss files. I get this error:

```
   Warning: LoadError on line ["1"] of /Users/antonioortiz/Sites/_aortizRefresh_/app/_bower_components/refills/lib/refills.rb: 
   cannot load such file -- refills/import_generator

   Run with --trace to see the full backtrace Use --force to continue.
```

I am using `bower` to manage my all my libraries and plugins, I believe best practice is to leave all those files `_bower_components` folder for updating and if you're going to port your project.

Anyway I am wonder if that's my problem. I have a `sass` folder which is linking to the `_bower_components` folder.

```
@import "../_bower_components/refills/source/stylesheets/all";
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
 Warning: LoadError on line ["1"] of /Users/antonioortiz/Sites/_aortizRefresh_/app/_bower_components/refills/lib/refills.rb: cannot load such file -- refills/import_generator
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace Use --force to continue.
```

Should I just dump the `refills` files in my `sass` folder?